# How to replace a div in Dojo? Div is repeatedly displayed on each click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dojo

On a drop down select, I show a div dynamically using below code: which is nothing but a dojo file uploader. On drop down select, it call below function and appends file upload code on html.

```
            showAttach (parser, Uploader, dom, on, has, templateID) {


                parser.parse(document.getElementById("container"));

                var uploaderDIV = document.getElementById("uploader");
                var templateID = document.getElementById('templateID').value;

                var uploadFormWithParams = "/wps//UploaderServlet?templateID=" + templateID;

                if ( document.getElementById('uploaderDIV') !=null && document.getElementById('uploaderDIV').style.display == 'block' ) {
                  //  alert("select - " + document.getElementById('uploaderDIV').style.display);
                    dijit.byId("uploaderDIV").remove();
                }

                var up = new dojox.form.Uploader({
                    label: 'Select files',
                    style: 'background-color: #ddddff; border: solid 0px;', //Externalize ...
                    multiple: true,
                    /* data: { product: "product", productFamily : "productFamily", productFamily : "operation"} ,*/
                    url: uploadFormWithParams
                }).placeAt(uploaderDIV);

                on(dom.byId("uploadBtn"), "click", function (evt) {
                    //You can put some validations here ...
                    up.submit();
                });

                on(dom.byId("clearBtn"), "click", function (evt) {
                    dom.byId("uploaderStatus").innerHTML = "";
                    up.reset();
                });

                dojo.connect(up, "onComplete", function (dataArray) {
                    var i = 0;

                    dom.byId("uploaderStatus").innerHTML = "";

                    if (!dataArray.error) {
                        for (i = 0; i < dataArray.length; ++i) {
                            //dom.byId("uploaderStatus").innerHTML += "File : '" + dataArray[i].name + "' is is saved for selected Email template." + "<br/><br/><br/>";
                            dom.byId("uploaderStatus").innerHTML += "'" + dataArray[i].status + " !'" + "<br/><br/><br/>";
                        }
                    } else {
                        dom.byId("uploaderStatus").innerHTML = "Unable to upload the file(s)";
                    }
                });

                dojo.connect(up, "onChange", function (evt) {
                    var i = 0;
                    var content = "";
                    var dataArray = up.getFileList();

                    for (i = 0; i < dataArray.length; ++i) {
                        content += dataArray[i].name + "<br/>";
                    }

                    dom.byId("uploaderStatus").innerHTML = content;
                });

                up.startup();
            }
```

First time, it works all fine, but when I select a second drop down. Instead of replacing the "uploaderDIV", it adds one more with proper mapping [query paramater goes correct when ajax call is made on up.on shown above].

What should I do in order to replace it with new uploaderDIV whenever dropdown value is changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two choices, you can either try to reuse the Uploader widget, or you can destroy the old one before you create the new one.

There are many ways to find the old widget, but the simplest is probably to give it an id, and use that with (dijit/registry) registry.byId("upId") to get the old Uploader widget to either reuse or to call up.destroy() before creating the new one.

I see you are referencing dijit.byId, my answer was assuming AMD where you would be you would use registry.byId.  But is you want to try to reuse the uploader (sorry about not cleaning up the formatting):

```
            showAttach (parser, Uploader, dom, on, has, templateID) {


            parser.parse(document.getElementById("container"));

            var uploaderDIV = document.getElementById("uploader");
            var templateID = document.getElementById('templateID').value;

            var uploadFormWithParams = "/wps//UploaderServlet?templateID=" + templateID;

            if ( document.getElementById('uploaderDIV') !=null && document.getElementById('uploaderDIV').style.display == 'block' ) {
              //  alert("select - " + document.getElementById('uploaderDIV').style.display);
                dijit.byId("uploaderDIV").remove();
            }
            var up = dijit.byId('myUploader');
            if(!up) {
              up = new dojox.form.Uploader({
                id: 'myUploader',
                label: 'Select files',
                style: 'background-color: #ddddff; border: solid 0px;', //Externalize ...
                multiple: true,
                /* data: { product: "product", productFamily : "productFamily", productFamily : "operation"} ,*/
                url: uploadFormWithParams
            }).placeAt(uploaderDIV);

            on(dom.byId("uploadBtn"), "click", function (evt) {
                //You can put some validations here ...
                up.submit();
            });

            on(dom.byId("clearBtn"), "click", function (evt) {
                dom.byId("uploaderStatus").innerHTML = "";
                up.reset();
            });

            dojo.connect(up, "onComplete", function (dataArray) {
                var i = 0;

                dom.byId("uploaderStatus").innerHTML = "";

                if (!dataArray.error) {
                    for (i = 0; i < dataArray.length; ++i) {
                        //dom.byId("uploaderStatus").innerHTML += "File : '" + dataArray[i].name + "' is is saved for selected Email template." + "<br/><br/><br/>";
                        dom.byId("uploaderStatus").innerHTML += "'" + dataArray[i].status + " !'" + "<br/><br/><br/>";
                    }
                } else {
                    dom.byId("uploaderStatus").innerHTML = "Unable to upload the file(s)";
                }
            });

            dojo.connect(up, "onChange", function (evt) {
                var i = 0;
                var content = "";
                var dataArray = up.getFileList();

                for (i = 0; i < dataArray.length; ++i) {
                    content += dataArray[i].name + "<br/>";
                }

                dom.byId("uploaderStatus").innerHTML = content;
            });

            up.startup();
          }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! I am new to dojo; could you please help how will I reuse that? with that uploader code pasted above?

Comment: I mean, at what point in the code, can I call registry.byId("upId") because as per above code, whenever dropdown changes, it calls this function and re-initializes "up" .

Comment: If you really need to have the Uploader recreated on each change, then you would remove the if(!up) line and replace it with up.destroy(); or maybe up.destroyRecursive(); would be better, and then let it recreate the upLoader.

Comment: when I used below code, it gave be "undefined" error.

Comment: var up = dijit.byId('myUploader');
          up.destroyRecursive();
              up = new dojox.form.Uploader({
                id: 'myUploader',
                label: 'Select files',
                style: 'background-color: #ddddff; border: solid 0px;', //Externalize ...
                multiple: true,
                /* data: { product: "product", productFamily : "productFamily", productFamily : "operation"} ,*/
                url: uploadFormWithParams
            }).placeAt(uploaderDIV);

Comment: even after using if(!up) as well .. getting undefined is not a function error .. I am sorry; I am very bad at javascript , dojo.

Comment: Which line is getting the error?  And what version of dojo are you using?

Comment: 1.8 and at var up = dijit .... line ... I guess this is because when first time this function is called ; it doesnr find the uploader div

Comment: TypeError: dom.byId is not a function is d error in mozilla

Comment: I would expect up to be undefined after the 1st call to var up = dijit.byId('myUploader'); but that should not be an error.  So you would need to have the if (!up) {up.destroy();} to avoid an error on the destroy() call.  Sorry I missed that originally.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72251/discussion-between-angryjs-and-edchat).